# How to remove suffix slash "/" from the assets url in webpack | Gatsby

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I am generating a build from webpack. But whenever it generates a build it creates an `index.html` file along with other files but in the `index.html` it adds `script` tags with the suffix "/". I want to add a configuration in webpack to just add the name of the files of different assets instead of the suffix "/"

My index.html:

```
<head>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Gatsby 2.1.19" />
  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/component---src-templates-all-pokemon-js-d59d33d2742ee8d7199e.js" />
  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/app-a6912420758bcc3e24a1.js" />
  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/webpack-runtime-65c9ddc0802b64490fd8.js" />
  <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/static/d/382/path---index-6a9-UNWMCjcHKgbI17oOwICQKH7zPs.json"
    crossorigin="use-credentials" />
</head>
```

But I want it like this for each and everything.

```
<head>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Gatsby 2.1.19" />
  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="component---src-templates-all-pokemon-js-d59d33d2742ee8d7199e.js" />
  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="app-a6912420758bcc3e24a1.js" />
  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="webpack-runtime-65c9ddc0802b64490fd8.js" />
  <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="static/d/382/path---index-6a9-UNWMCjcHKgbI17oOwICQKH7zPs.json"
    crossorigin="use-credentials" />
</head>
```

I know that I have to change my webpack configurations, but I am unable to do that for all the asset files in a Gatsby. I want to do it for each and every file I am loading from my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any way of removing the beginning slash but if your gatsby site is not the root of your domain, for example `www.example.com/blog/` you can use path prefix.

From [the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/)

> There are two steps for building a site with path prefixes.
>
> 1. First define the prefix in your site’s gatsby-config.js.
>
> *gatsby-config.js*
>
> ```js
>     module.exports = {
>         // Note: it must *not* have a trailing slash.
>         pathPrefix: `/blog`,
>     }
> ```
>
> 2. Then pass `--prefix-paths` cmd option to Gatsby.
>
>    `gatsby build --prefix-paths`

Comment: I know about the path prefix. I want to know about the assets. The thing is I am serving multiple websites from a single S3 bucket. So whenever it finds '/' in the resource url it goes to root instead of finding the asset in that particular folder. I mannualy tried to remove all the slashes from index.html but I am getting some react errors on the console and the assets are not loading properly.

Comment: Why do you need a single bucket for multiple websites?

Comment: @AlqamaBinSadiq I don't get it. `path-prefix` works for everything, could you give us an ewample where it doesn't apply ?

Comment: pathPrefix is for the URL not for the assets. I just want to remove all the prefix slash from all the assets URLs

Comment: @ksav I am working on a website builder and I need to serve multiple websites on a different URLs under the same domain.

Comment: `pathPrefix` won't remove the first slash but it will set the aset url accordingly to the specified directory : the asset URL will be `/{pathPrefix}/assetURL` instead of `/assetURL`. But you have to know the directory at build time